# Blade syntax @extends loads second HTML view and then the first HTML view

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and blade template engine.
Issue: file form.blade.php

@extends('front.header')
@extends('front.footer')

Loads front/footer.blade.php first and then the contents of front/header.blade.php

Please find attached the snap shot of the View Source.

I have checked few answers in stackoverflow they say about the white space.I dont seem to have any.

Regards,
Jignesh[image]

Comment: You cannot extends from 2 parents. If you want to include another view, you should use `@include('front.header')` and `@include('front.footer')`

Comment: I posted an answer for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `@extends` from 2 parents. If you want to include another view, you should use `@include` instead

Like this :

```
@include('front.header')
Content
@include('front.footer')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would recommend structuring your master template.

#### *front._layouts.master:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  @include('front._layouts.head')
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      @include('front._layouts.header')
  </header>

  <main>
      @yield('content')
  </main>

  <footer>
    @include('front._layouts.header')
  </footer>
  @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `@stack()` this can come in useful when you're making a robust part of an application. **[Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#stacks)** allow you to push to named stacks on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

step 1:

> resources\views create a file like: master.blade.php

step 2:

> resources\views create a folder like: layouts

Inside `layout` folder create your  `header` & `footer` file

step 3:

inside `master.blade.php` write how you design your main template like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- your common css here -->

        @yield('partial-css')

    </head>

    <body>
        @include('layouts.top-header')             

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content') <!-- this is your common body -->
        </div> <!-- /container --> 

        @include('layouts.footer')

        <!-- your common js here or you also define inside the footer page -->

        @yield('script') <!-- this is your individual script for all page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Step 4:
Now you use master page for all other pages like so `index.blade.php`

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

<!-- Here is your main body content -->

@endsection

@section('script')

<!-- Here is your individual script content -->

@endsection
```

Hope you understand now how blade template works!